# What does this curly brace block do after a var declaration?

Tags: swift

I'm looking at this Swift code:

```
var modelController: ModelController {
    if _modelController == nil {
        _modelController = ModelController()
    }
    return _modelController!
}

var _modelController: ModelController? = nil
```

What interests me is the first line: it's declaring a variable named `modelController` of type `ModelController`, followed by some code surrounded by curly braces, which I think is called a closure in Swift.

What does this closure do? When is it executed? What is this pattern called? I'm using Swift 3.

Comment: Look up "computed property" in the Swift reference ...

Comment: Just found it, thanks @MartinR. I wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is called a [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259). The kind you're seeing here is a read-only computed property.

Everytime you access the property (`self.modelController` in this case), the closure runs, returning the value that will be used for the property.

In the example given, the code checks whether another variable `_modelController` is set, and sets it if not, then returns that value. This is a way of lazy loading the object when it is accessed for the first time.

Comment: Swift has also `lazy` properties, so you actually seldom use this pattern (unless you translate Objective-C code literally).

Comment: @MartinR That's fascinating. The code I'm quoting is starting code from Xcode, I'm surprised it wouldn't use the idiomatic Swift way.

Comment: @MartinR Xcode 8.0, "file", "new", "project", "page-based application", and then the file `RootViewController.swift`.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you can achieve the same with `lazy var modelController = ModelController()`, without the additional underscore property.

Comment: Can someone also explain me this e.g. var name: String { "George" }, why not just do var name: String = "George" ? Why use the curly brackets?

Comment: @AdrianL I don't use Swift much any more. This sounds like a new question, try posting a new question post.